# How do I insert an entry into a SQL Server database and return inserted columns including primary key identity with one command in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an `Occasion` object which includes a string `description`, an int `fundId`, a datetime `date` and int `occasionId`. The same fields are in my SQL Server database with `OccasionId` being the primary key (auto incremented).

I'm trying to insert a new entry and return all fields into an `Occasion` object. Here is my current code which is not working:

```
public Occasion InsertNewOccasion(string description, DateTime date, int fundId)
{
    Occasion occasion = new Occasion();

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT into Occasions OUTPUT INSERTED.Description, INSERTED.Date values(@description, @date, @fundId); SELECT @@identity AS OccasionId", connection);

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", description);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fundId", fundId);

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            occasion.Description = (string) reader["Description"];
            occasion.Date = (DateTime) reader["Date"];
            occasion.OccasionId = (int) reader["OccasionId"];
        }
    }

    return occasion;
}
```

Comment: Or just use Entity Framework which supports this out of the box..... (store the entity, and get the auto-incremented `ID` back *for free*) .....

Answer (score 2):

You have over-complicated the SQL. Use this:

```
INSERT into Occasions ([description], [date], [fundId]) OUTPUT INSERTED.OccasionId, INSERTED.Description, INSERTED.Date values (@description, @date, @fundId);
```

Remember, the `INSERTED` psuedo-table is the same as would be available in a trigger. Hence, it has access to *all* columns in the table, even auto-incremented ones.

**BUT**, I would also recommend just using the current variables to set `occasion.Description` and `occasion.Date` since you are already passing those in. This way you don't have to waste the effort getting them back and then casting them when they are already there in their proper types.

1) Change the SQL to be just:

```
INSERT INTO Occasions ([description], [date], [fundId]) OUTPUT INSERTED.OccasionId VALUES (@description, @date, @fundId);
```

2) Change the C# to be:

{replace the following}

```cs
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            occasion.Description = (string) reader["Description"];
            occasion.Date = (DateTime) reader["Date"];
            occasion.OccasionId = (int) reader["OccasionId"];
        }
```

{with the following}

```cs
occasion.OccasionId = (int)(command.ExecuteScalar());
occasion.Description = description;
occasion.Date = date;
```

Comment: @MirrorEyes Please see my additional notes regarding how to simplify the C# code. You are currently doing more work than necessary.

Comment: @MirrorEyes also, if this did work, please don't forget to mark as "accepted" (the check-mark next to this answer). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change your sql command line to something like this:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT into Occasions (Description, Date, FundID) SELECT @description, @date, @fundId; SELECT Description, Date, OccasionId  FROM Occasions WHERE OccasionId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()", connection);
```

Also, per @JamesZ, this is assuming OccasionId is and Identity field

Comment: This is both error prone and unnecessary. Error prone due to using `@@IDENTITY` instead of `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. Unnecessary due to an extra lookup when the values are already available via the `OUTPUT` clause, which the O.P. was already using.

Comment: Thanks. And to clarify why `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`: it is not susceptible to getting the identity of another table inserted into via a trigger on this table, whereas `@@IDENTITY` is. Hence the "error prone".

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking something like this:

```
INSERT into Occasions  (Description, Date, fundId)
output inserted.Description, inserted.Date, inserted,OccasionId
values (@description, @date, @fundId)
```

Assuming you have OccasionID column in the table that is identity.